# Euclidean distance point Cloud clustering in R lidR

Tags: r, lidar, clustering, lidr, point-cloud

I'm looking for a way to implement the python function [filter.clusters](https://pdal.io/en/2.4.3/stages/filters.cluster.html) from the [pdal](https://pdal.io/) package in R using the [lidR](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/index.html) package.
The function clusters pointclouds using the Euclidean distance, a tolerance threshhold and adds a clusterID to each point. It takes essentially takes three inputs:

1. A las file / las object
2. **min_points**: the minimum Number of points to be considered a cluster
3. **tolerance**: The maximum Euclidean distance for a point to be added to the cluster

I've tried the locate_ and segment_trees functions in the lidR package but couldn't quite get there as these functions are designed to work with tree shaped structures as opposed to the more flat roof buildings I'm trying to segment.

**Q:** Given the following point cloud is there a function in the lidR packaged designed or able to assign a clusterID to each point based on the Euclidean distance?

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las <- lidR::readLAS(LASfile, filter = "-drop_z_below 26")
lidR::plot(las)
```

[image]

Comment: No, you must look at third party packages. There are tons of packages for clustering. But Euclidean Cluster Extraction maybe not.